# Declaring queue in c++

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to declare a queue in c++:

```
#include <queue>
......
......
queue<Process> *readyQueue = new queue<Process>;
.......
```

But i keep getting this error

> 'queue' was not declared in this scope

What am I missing? I, of course, created the Process struct, so the problem isn't there.
What's the issue?

Comment: Do **not** use `new` unless you **know** you need to use `new`! I very much doubt you need to use `new`. C++ is not C# or Java.

Comment: Your problem is that `std::queue<T>` is declared in namespace `std`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl when I add the std:: i get these errors,
expected type-specifier before 'queue'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'std::queue<Process>*'

Comment: @user1929226 where's the error occurs?

Comment: @user1929226 maybe you're tryin to do something like `readyQueue.push(/* int* type */);`

Comment: @user1929226: Given the mutilated example, I can't tell what your code would look like, but I do know that `std::queue<Process>` should work better than `queue<Process>`.

Answer (score 19):

You are missing namespace specification. I suppose you want std functions.
Use either:

```
 #include <queue>
 ......
 std::queue<Process> *readyQueue = new std::queue<Process>;
```

or

```
 #include <queue>
 using std::queue;
 ......
 queue<Process> *readyQueue = new queue<Process>;
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this answer comment on the reason for the downvote? Given that the fix is the correct fix, it is entirely unwarranted.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the correct namespace

`std::queue`

Comment: when i do so, i get these errors: 
expected type-specifier before 'queue'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'std::queue<Process>*'

Comment: A whole othef problem.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `using namespace std;` or the `std::` prefix. This might help you:

```
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    Process p1;
    Process p2;

    std::queue<Process> readyQueue;
    readyQueue.push(p1);
    readyQueue.push(p2);
}
```

See [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) for more details.

Comment: [`using namespace std`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is not so cool. Other than that the answer is completely correct.

Comment: @juanchopanza, you're right. Just an another option. In ordinary, i'm trying to avoid this at all and use std:: prefix.